# Get all values from an XML column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a COTS application that has an audit table with an XML formatted column in it.  I am trying to parse all the data so I can write an SSRS report to be customer facing.  The application writes the original data and the changed value to the XML column when the system saves.  This means that the column may contain one or many values and may be one of many types of data modified.

I am wanting to end up with a query that will show what data was changed and to what.

1. Can I write a query that would return all the values that exist in the column so in worst case scenario I could explicitly write out every value that has happened so far?
2. Is it possible to have it just dynamically pull the data while identifying what the data is?

Example XML Entry:

```
<LogMessage>
   <Fields>
      <TransactionCount />
      <PersonnelType>
          <OldValue> Contractor </OldValue>
          <NewValue> Employee </NewValue>
      </PersonnelType>
      <Disabled>
          <OldValue> TRUE </OldValue>
          <NewValue> FALSE </NewValue>
      </Disabled>
      <Expiration>
          <OldValue> 10/31/2018</OldValue>
          <NewValue> 12/31/2019 </NewValue>
      </Expiration>
   </Fields>
</LogMessage>
```

The transaction count above just indicates it was changed but isn't tracked. So I've just been doing a CASE statement that if it existed return a value and if not leave it NULL.  In all the entries I've looked at the old value is always before the new value.

Each cell can have one or many entries and there is no way to tell what they will be ahead of time.

I started down the path looking in the cells and just calling each possible instance to extract the data.

```
XML.value('(LogMessage/Fields/Disabled/OldValue)[1]','varchar(5)') AS 'Old_Disabled'
XML.value('(LogMessage/Fields/Disabled/NewValue)[1]','varchar(5)') AS 'New_Disabled'
```

Then I was going to try to do some sort of concatenation logic when not null using TSQL.

I used this piece of code that returned all the values, but since it stripped all the tag information I couldn't determine what was changed

```
XML.value('(LogMessage/Fields)[1]','varchar(max)') AS 'Raw_Data'
```

The above string against the example would return this (all values,no spaces, no indication of what the value represents): ContractorEmployeeTRUEFALSE10/31/201812/31/2019

If there is a way to modify the above code to return something along the lines of this it would be great, but it would need to be dynamic.

PersonnelType Old: Contractor New: Employee

Disabled Old: True New: False

Expiration Old: 10/31/2018 NEW: 12/31/2019

Even this would be awesome:

PersonnelType Contractor, Employee

Disabled True, Yes

Expiration 10/31/2018, 12/31/2019

Comment: Isn't the new value of `Disabled` `FALSE`, not `Yes`?

Comment: You are correct, it should be FALSE.  I will update it.  That was just a typo on my part.  Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not state your expected output clearly, but this seems to be rather easy. XML can deal with generic structures quite well:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<LogMessage>
   <Fields>
      <TransactionCount />
      <PersonnelType>
          <OldValue> Contractor </OldValue>
          <NewValue> Employee </NewValue>
      </PersonnelType>
      <Disabled>
          <OldValue> TRUE </OldValue>
          <NewValue> FALSE </NewValue>
      </Disabled>
      <Expiration>
          <OldValue> 10/31/2018</OldValue>
          <NewValue> 12/31/2019 </NewValue>
      </Expiration>
   </Fields>
</LogMessage>';
```

--The query will use `.nodes()` with a path to `/*`.
--This will return all elements below `<Fields>`, however they are named
--The query will return the element's name (`local-name(.)`) together with the two nested elements for old and new value:

```
SELECT fld.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS FieldName
      ,fld.value('(OldValue/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS OldValue
      ,fld.value('(NewValue/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS NewValue
FROM @xml.nodes('/LogMessage/Fields/*') A(fld);
```

The result

```
FieldName           OldValue    NewValue
-----------------------------------------
TransactionCount    NULL        NULL
PersonnelType       Contractor  Employee 
Disabled            TRUE        FALSE 
Expiration          10/31/2018  12/31/2019
```

### UPDATE

The same against a table's column:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,YourXml XML)
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
('<LogMessage>
   <Fields>
      <TransactionCount />
      <PersonnelType>
          <OldValue> Contractor </OldValue>
          <NewValue> Employee </NewValue>
      </PersonnelType>
      <Disabled>
          <OldValue> TRUE </OldValue>
          <NewValue> FALSE </NewValue>
      </Disabled>
      <Expiration>
          <OldValue> 10/31/2018</OldValue>
          <NewValue> 12/31/2019 </NewValue>
      </Expiration>
   </Fields>
</LogMessage>');

SELECT fld.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS FieldName
      ,fld.value('(OldValue/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS OldValue
      ,fld.value('(NewValue/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS NewValue
FROM @mockup m
OUTER APPLY m.YourXml.nodes('/LogMessage/Fields/*') A(fld)
```

Comment: That works incredibly well.  Thank you.  Is there a way to tie the results to which entry they came from.  For example, I may be running an audit report that goes back 4 months and so I have 10 entries against me.  This displays them all in the one table.  So if I have entry 1 with PersonnelType, Disabled, and Expiration values, and entry 2 with Name, Schedule, PayGrade, etc.

Comment: @CPickler please use my mockup scenario and place something similar into your question. Provide some realistic XMLs and the expected output.

Comment: Nevermind, just realized I can still call the other columns like usual within this select statement.

Answer (score 3):

I have used [OPENXML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openxml-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), please check if this is appropriate.

```
DECLARE @InputXml xml;
set @InputXml ='<LogMessage>
   <Fields>
      <TransactionCount />
      <PersonnelType>
          <OldValue> Contractor </OldValue>
          <NewValue> Employee </NewValue>
      </PersonnelType>
      <Disabled>
          <OldValue> TRUE </OldValue>
          <NewValue> FALSE </NewValue>
      </Disabled>
      <Expiration>
          <OldValue> 10/31/2018</OldValue>
          <NewValue> 12/31/2019 </NewValue>
      </Expiration>
   </Fields>
</LogMessage>'

select @InputXml

declare @idoc int
exec sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc out, @InputXml

select FieldName, 
       replace(FieldValue, '  ', ', ') as value
from openxml(@idoc, '/LogMessage/Fields/*',2) 
  with (
         FieldName  varchar(50) '@mp:localname',
         FieldValue varchar(50) '.'
       )

exec sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
```

[RexTesterDEMO](https://rextester.com/LJLOGA79966)

Comment: This looks great.  I'm not very familiar with OpenXML, but looking at it in the RexTester that looks great.  Is there a way to have the variable dynamically pull the values that will appear without hardcoding it?  The XML entries could have any number of entries and I want something that will dynamically parse the values.  I know for your example you had to declare something, but can I set the @InputXML variable to dbname.AuditView.XML or something like that?  The XML column is just one of many columns in the view.

Comment: `FROM OPENXML` with the corresponding SPs to prepare and to remove a document is outdated and should not be used any more. Rather use the appropriate [methods the XML data type provides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx). These methods can work against a tables column in ad-hoc queries, while this approach needs to use a procedural set of steps

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this answer for your only one part i.e., tacking update in table. You can write a trigger which will track the update/change in table dynamically. Below is that SQL server code of trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_Employee_AUDIT] ON [dbo].[Employee_mstr] FOR UPDATE
AS

DECLARE @bit INT ,
       @field INT ,
       @maxfield INT ,
       @char INT ,
       @fieldname VARCHAR(128) ,
       @TableName VARCHAR(128) ,
       @PKCols VARCHAR(1000) ,
       @sql VARCHAR(2000), 
       @UpdateDate VARCHAR(21) ,
       @UserName VARCHAR(128) ,
       @Type CHAR(1) ,
       @PKSelect VARCHAR(1000),
       @empcode VARCHAR(20)


--You will need to change @TableName to match the table to be audited. 
-- Here we made GUESTS for your example.
SELECT @TableName = 'Employee_Mstr'

-- date and user
SELECT         @UserName = SYSTEM_USER ,
       @UpdateDate = CONVERT (NVARCHAR(30),GETDATE(),126)

-- Action
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted)
       IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
               SELECT @Type = 'U'
       ELSE
               SELECT @Type = 'I'
ELSE
       SELECT @Type = 'D'

-- get list of columns
SELECT * INTO #ins FROM inserted
SELECT * INTO #del FROM deleted

select @UserName = EMP_ModifiedBy, @empcode = emp_cd from #ins
if isnull(@UserName,'') = ''
select @UserName = EMP_ModifiedBy, @empcode = emp_cd from #del

-- Get primary key columns for full outer join
SELECT @PKCols = COALESCE(@PKCols + ' and', ' on') 
               + ' i.' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ' = d.' + c.COLUMN_NAME
       FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ,

              INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
       WHERE   pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
       AND     CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
       AND     c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
       AND     c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME

-- Get primary key select for insert
SELECT @PKSelect = COALESCE(@PKSelect+'+','') 
       + '''<' + COLUMN_NAME 
       + '=''+convert(varchar(100),
coalesce(i.' + COLUMN_NAME +',d.' + COLUMN_NAME + '))+''>''' 
       FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ,
               INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
       WHERE   pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
       AND     CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
       AND     c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
       AND     c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME

IF @PKCols IS NULL
BEGIN
       RAISERROR('no PK on table %s', 16, -1, @TableName)
       RETURN
END


SELECT         @field = 0, 
       @maxfield = MAX(ORDINAL_POSITION) 
       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName
       AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('EMP_ModifiedOn','EMP_ModifiedBy')
WHILE @field < @maxfield
BEGIN
       SELECT @field = MIN(ORDINAL_POSITION) 
               FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
               WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName 
               AND ORDINAL_POSITION > @field
               AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('EMP_ModifiedOn','EMP_ModifiedBy')
       SELECT @bit = (@field - 1 )% 8 + 1
       SELECT @bit = POWER(2,@bit - 1)
       SELECT @char = ((@field - 1) / 8) + 1
       IF SUBSTRING(COLUMNS_UPDATED(),@char, 1) & @bit > 0
                                       OR @Type IN ('I','D')
       BEGIN
               SELECT @fieldname = COLUMN_NAME 
                       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                       WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName 
                       AND ORDINAL_POSITION = @field
                       AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('EMP_ModifiedOn','EMP_ModifiedBy')
               SELECT @sql = '
insert NewAuditLog (    Type, 
               TableName, 
               PK, 
               FieldName, 
               OldValue, 
               NewValue, 
               UpdateDate, 
               UserName)
select ''' + @Type + ''',''' 
       + @TableName + ''',''' + @empcode + ''',''' + @fieldname + ''''
       + ',convert(varchar(1000),d.' + @fieldname + ')'
       + ',convert(varchar(1000),i.' + @fieldname + ')'
       + ',''' + @UpdateDate + ''''
       + ',''' + @UserName + ''''
       + ' from #ins i full outer join #del d'
       + @PKCols
       + ' where i.' + @fieldname + ' <> d.' + @fieldname 
       + ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is null and  d.'
                                + @fieldname
                                + ' is not null)' 
       + ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is not null and  d.' 
                                + @fieldname
                                + ' is null)' 
               EXEC (@sql)
       END
END
```

You need to create a table for storing changed value as shown below.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NewAuditLog](
    [Type] [char](1) NULL,
    [TableName] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [PK] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [FieldName] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [OldValue] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [NewValue] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [UpdateDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [UserName] [varchar](128) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Once data will be changed in table the output will be stored as shown below

[image: Update Tracking]

Comment: Thank you very much for this informative response.  Unfortunately, for my purposes the changes are all over hundreds of tables and already getting loaded into a single auditing point with lots of columns.  They just utilize XML and I'm trying to figure out a better way of parsing all the data that exists or may exist.  I may end up using this information in another project however.  Thank you.